# Change the icons of buttons on login-screen after log-out on Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS

Tags: gnome, button, icon-themes

On my lock-screen, the buttons look like this:
[image]

But after I log-out or restart my computer, the buttons on the lock screen, look like this: [image]

I want the buttons on my lock screen, after log-out, to look like the same (like the 1st picture).

Also, you may see that I have a white border around my user picture (on my 1st picture), which I would like to remove. I know it's possible because of the 2nd picture.

Comment: did you install flat-remix themes manually or via apt??

Comment: via synaptic package manager

Comment: Here is a picture of it: [Click here](https://i.imgur.com/DQguf0k.png)

Comment: which desktop session are you in? `printf 'Desktop: %s\nSession: %s\n' "$XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP" "$GDMSESSION"` run this command and paste the output

Comment: Desktop: ubuntu:GNOME
Session: ubuntu

Comment: ok.. did you select this session manually? did you install desktop session separately or it came with flat-remix?

Comment: I didn't select this session. I've installed the flat-remix with `synaptic package manager` and changed the theme in `gnome-tweaks`.

Comment: i am just thinking if it is default ubuntu session.. it should show purple background at lock screen.. but yours is showing grey...

Comment: It's because I've changed `/usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/ubuntu.css`, like [here](https://vitux.com/8-ways-to-customize-your-ubuntu-desktop/)

Comment: thats great! very valuable info to solve your question..can you open the same file and paste the content here few lines where you changed.. i think you only changed the color rite..

Comment: `#lockDialogGroup {
  background: #2c001e url(file:////usr/share/backgrounds/loginscreen.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}`

Comment: Ok.. so you made a loginscreen.jpg image, can you provide that image, mean while i write the answer..

Comment: here you go: [loginscreen.jpg](https://i.imgur.com/rspqGIJ.jpg)

Comment: When I lock my screen, loginscreen.jpg is shown

Answer (score 1):

your lock screen is using `/usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/ubuntu.css` file
and the login screen is using `/usr/share/themes/Flat-Remix/gnome-shell/gnome-shell.css`

run the below command
`sudo update-alternatives --config gdm3.css`

select the number corresponding to `/usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/ubuntu.css`

Example:

```
pratap@i7-6550U:~$ sudo update-alternatives --config gdm3.css
There are 6 choices for the alternative gdm3.css (providing /usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/gdm3.css).

  Selection    Path                                                                 Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
* 0            /usr/share/themes/Flat-Remix/gnome-shell/gnome-shell.css              20        auto mode
  1            /usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/ubuntu.css                               10        manual mode
  2            /usr/share/themes/Flat-Remix-Dark/gnome-shell/gnome-shell.css         17        manual mode
  3            /usr/share/themes/Flat-Remix-Darkest/gnome-shell/gnome-shell.css      17        manual mode
  4            /usr/share/themes/Flat-Remix-Miami-Dark/gnome-shell/gnome-shell.css   17        manual mode
  5            /usr/share/themes/Flat-Remix-Miami/gnome-shell/gnome-shell.css        17        manual mode
  6            /usr/share/themes/Flat-Remix/gnome-shell/gnome-shell.css              20        manual mode

Press <enter> to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number: 1   
update-alternatives: using /usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/ubuntu.css to provide /usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/gdm3.css (gdm3.css) in manual mode
pratap@i7-6550U:~$
```

this way what ever the changes we make to ubuntu.css file, will apply to both login screen and unlock screen..

Login Screen
[image]

Unlock Screen
[image]

to remove the white border around the user logo..

open the file `/usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/ubuntu.css` with your favorite editor..

mine is gedit.. so
`sudo -H gedit /usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/ubuntu.css`

find the content

```
/* Auth Dialogs & Screen Shield */
.framed-user-icon {
  background-size: contain;
  border: 2px solid #eeeeec;
  color: #eeeeec;
  border-radius: 3px; }
  .framed-user-icon:hover {
    border-color: white;
    color: white; }
```

and make the required changes as per your need..
i have changed like this..

```
/* Auth Dialogs & Screen Shield */
.framed-user-icon {
  background-size: contain;
  border: 0;
  color: #eeeeec;
  border-radius: 3px; }
  .framed-user-icon:hover {
    border-color: white;
    color: white; }
```

and the result is

[image]

[image]